# Can't allocate complex 2D array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a "union-find".

Here is my code :

```
UnionFind uf_create(){
    UnionFind uf= malloc(sizeof(UnionFind));
    uf->vt=malloc(11*sizeof(VertexTree*));
    uf->nbElems=VERTEX_MAX;
    uf->nbGroups=VERTEX_MAX;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<uf->nbElems;i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        uf->vt[i]->vtx=i+1;
        uf->vt[i]->parent=uf->vt[i];
    }
    return uf;
}
```

The UnionFind is defined by :

```
typedef struct unionfind{
    unsigned int nbElems;
    unsigned int nbGroups;
    VertexTree **vt;
}*UnionFind;
```

And here is the definition of the Tree :

```
typedef struct sTree{
    GraphVertex vtx;
    struct sTree* parent;
}VertexTree;
```

I know the segfault is because the tree is not allocated correctly.
Can someone please tell me how to allocate memory correctly for the tree of vertices?

Thanks

Comment: Accessing `uf->vt[i]->vtx` causes undefined behavior. You should write a for loop initializing each vt[i] right after `uf->nbGroups=...`.

Comment: That's what I just did, now the segfault is happening in the line of allocation ("uf->vt[i]=malloc(sizeof(VertexTree));")

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 11; ++i) { uf->vt[i] = malloc(sizeof **uf->vt); }` is giving you segfault?

Comment: yes, but why `**uf->vt` ? sizeof only work with data types, right?

Comment: I tried `malloc(sizeof **uf->vt)` and it also gives me a segfault.

Comment: `sizeof **uf->vt` is equivalent to `sizeof(VertexTree)`, since `*(*(uf->vt))` is a `VertexTree`. If you do `sizeof uf->vt` you are writing sizeof(VertexTree **). `sizeof *uf->vt` equals `sizeof(VertexTree *)`. `sizeof **uf->vt` equals `sizeof(VertexTree)`. So, what is the difference after all? The difference is that if you change the type of `vt`, with my code you don't need to rewrite the `sizeof`. Take a look at [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Comment: I think I just found your problem. Try replacing `UnionFind uf= malloc(sizeof(UnionFind));` with `struct unionfind *uf = malloc(sizeof *uf);`. If this works, I'll write an answer explaining the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

I had to allocate the "pointer of pointers" (**vt) and then allocate the pointers for each tree in a for loop.

So the final code is :

`UnionFind uf_create(){
    UnionFind uf= malloc(sizeof(UnionFind));
    uf->nbElems=VERTEX_MAX;
    uf->nbGroups=VERTEX_MAX;
    uf->vt=malloc(VERTEX_MAX*sizeof(VertexTree*));//uf->vt is now defined
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<uf->nbElems;i++){
        uf->vt[i]=malloc(sizeof(VertexTree));//I can now allocate the trees one by one
        uf->vt[i]->vtx=i+1;
        uf->vt[i]->parent=uf->vt[i];
    }
    return uf;
}`

Comment: Remember what I told you about `sizeof`? `UnionFind uf = malloc(sizeof(UnionFind));` is seen by the compiler as `struct unionfind *uf = malloc(sizeof(struct unionfind *));`, which is wrong. You are allocating space for a **pointer** of `struct unionfind` when you actually want space for a `struct unionfind`. Change it to `UnionFind uf = malloc(sizeof *uf);` and see if it still works.

Comment: Btw, you were already allocating "the pointer of pointers" with `uf->vt=malloc(11*sizeof(VertexTree*));`. I thought that `11 == VERTEX_MAX`, otherwise your for loop was accessing indexes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`UnionFind uf= malloc(sizeof(UnionFind));`

I think this is your problem line..

`UnionFind` is a pointer type so `sizeof` will only return the size of a pointer for your machine.

Try:

`UnionFind uf= malloc(sizeof(struct unionfind));`

This will return the actual size of the structure.

Comment: @Elirovi if this answers your question, even if you did find the problem, consider accepting it as an answer. It could be a more detailed answer, but it still an answer.

Comment: I just tried with `struct unionfind` it didn't work. Sorry

Comment: Just curious, where did you get the segfault when you tried that?

Comment: @bhzag at the same line (`uf->vt[i]=malloc(sizeof(VertexTree));`)

Comment: @bhzag just realized that his for loop was iterating from `0 to VERTEX_MAX`, which seems to be much bigger than 11.